# Check if Facebook User logged in without PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-php-sdk

I’m trying to emulate the Facebook login workflow by a self-written code (i.e. without using the Facebook PHP SDK), according to Facebook documentation this should be possible and quite simple:

> “Apps using our SDKs can check whether someone has already logged in
>   using built-in functions. All other apps must create their own way of
>   storing when a person has logged in”

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2

My main motivation is that the frequent changes by Facebook and the SDKs are frustrating and urging me to migrate to native HTTP requests with self written libraries.

When using the SDK, process should be (this is with previous version):

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'     => MY_APP_ID,
    'secret'    => MY_APP_SECRET,
    ));
$this_user_facebook_id = $facebook->getUser(); // Get User ID
if($this_user_facebook_id > '0')
    {
    try
        {
        $user_access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
        // do whatever you like
        }
    }
catch(FacebookApiException $e)
    {
    print_r($e);
    $this_user_facebook_id = NULL;
    }
```

The process I’m trying to follow is:

- CURL to
  https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL&scope=MY_APPROVED_SCOPE
- Scrape the redirect URL - if it includes a "code=..." $_GET variable, it means that the user is logged in, and I could query the
  access_token. Otherwise, present a Facebook Login link

Issue is that I get dropped at this stage: I tried to read the Facebook redirect header until a realised that actually Facebook redirect the user with meta tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&amp;api_key=............ ------LONG FACEBOOK URL ------->
```

Issue is that I couldn't find the native URL there, i.e. the code=.... variable is missing even that the user **does get** redirected to `http://MY_APP_REDIRECT_URL/?code=`

I tried to read the CURL header but there is nothing there. I also tried to generate the APP access token and query the user access token through it (failed).

Any clues? Any ideas how to generate a native HTTP Graph API request that would lead to query the user access_token? I'm three days on the net trying to figure this out and the Facebook documentation is not so helpful as well.

Comment: Making a cURL request for the login dialog is wrong already; that URL has to be hit by the _user_ in _their browser_, and only after the redirect it is time for your app to take over again. // Seeing that you seem to have little idea of how this stuff actually works, I think it might be a better idea for you to stick with the official SDK; it doesn’t change as often as you suggest, and even if it does most of the time the changes are non-breaking ones (f.e. even though PHP SDK v4 has been out for over a year now, the old v3 can still be used to do most things.)

Comment: Everything "in the user browser" could be emulated, your attitude is not helping. If you think it is wrong to CURL the dialogue login, and you understand it so well, you are invited to suggest an alternative Re: the FB guidelines above. I didn't say I don't know how to work with SDK, I developed more than 25 sites with FB login and run through all the FB permissions and processes correctly. What I said that I don't WANT to work with the SDK, even that it is stable, it is quiet a bad piece of work.

Comment: _“Everything "in the user browser" could be emulated”_ – no, it can not in this case. The way this kind of login works, is that the user’s _browser_ is redirected to facebook.com, because only then the cookies set for that domain can be read, and those are used to determine if the user is currently logged in to Facebook. So when you cURL the login dialog instead, no such cookies will be send to Facebook, simply because there aren’t any. You can not log a user that is visiting your page into Facebook “in the background” by making a request to the login dialog from your server.

Comment: And this is btw. clearly mentioned on the docs page about the manual login flow, _“Your app must initiate **a redirect** to an endpoint which will display the login dialog”_

Comment: Obviously the SDK is not presenting the dialogue, unless you present the login URL. Again, your attitude is not helping - if you have spare time to bash people maybe do something useful instead. I already found some fractions of information which I should post later - you are wrong (and rude)

Comment: Beside, Facebook themselves give several frameworks to access the API - one of them (the default one) is native HTTP. PHP SDK is one of them only. Developers which stick to formal SDKs and can't do more than / emulate the same code in a simpler ways that are just amateurs.

Comment: I know that the API works via HTTP, the PHP SDK does nothing else but make HTTP requests to the API internally as well … and I did say nothing else either. But the _login dialog_ has to be called in the _user’s browser_, that’s just how OAuth works. So all you have to do is follow the documentation on building the manual login flow – send the user to the login dialog _in their browser_, and after they authorized your app they will be redirected back to your app, and then your app can get the `code` parameter from the URL and exchange that for an access token in the background.

Comment: FYI: What you are doing with your app on http://www.palrobot.com/ is against Platform Policies – you are not allowed to post stuff automatically on user timelines, not even with the user’s consent. If you publish something on a user timeline, then the user must actively trigger this for each and every single post, and any message must be a 100% user generated (i.e., typed in by the user) as well. You should really go read [Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy) before you continue.

Comment: PalRobot is now in review and re-coding and will do schedule posts and not automatic posts, what stands with their policy. It was developed before all the horrendous changes that Facebook imposed. But how does this relate to my question? Is this a coding help community or "bash your colleague + legal backdoor advice" forum? Maybe you should read the stackoverflow policies and please do it next time before you mark down a legit question. If you wanted to be helpful you could provide the Facebook REST method information which Facebook lack, or other ideas, instead of the above conversation.

Answer (score 3):

> “Apps using our SDKs can check whether someone has already logged in using built-in functions. All other apps must create their own way of storing when a person has logged in”

actually links to

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2#token

> Storing access tokens and login status
>
> At this point in the flow, you have someone authenticated and logged
> in. Your app is ready to make API calls on their behalf. Before doing
> so, it should store the access token and the login status of the
> person using the app.
>
> Storing access tokens
>
> After your app receives the access token from
> the previous step, the token should be stored so it's available to all
> parts of the app when it makes API calls. There is no specific process
> here, however in general if you're building a web app, it is best to
> add the token as a session variable to identify that browser session
> with a particular person, if you're building a native desktop or
> mobile app, then you should use the datastore available to your app.
> Also, the app should store the token in a database along with the
> user_id to identify it.
>
> Please see our note about the size of access tokens in the access
> token document.
>
> Tracking login status
>
> Again, your app should store a person's login
> status, which helps avoid having to make additional calls to the Login
> dialog. Whatever procedure you chose, modify your login status
> checking to account for it.

So they are saying that because they use for e.g. the JS SDK, a session is already stored by Facebook so getting login status can be done on the fly as opposed to the manual way.

I see you are also using the old PHP SDK

`$this_user_facebook_id = $facebook->getUser();`

If you inspect this function in the source https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php, you will see that what it does is check whether a user is set if not check for a user from available data. Available data here being in this order

- any [signed requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request)
- an authorization code
- then falling back to any persistent store storing the user.

If none of these are set then there is no valid user.

The simplest way to check similar via server is to store the user with an id and the access token (when they first authorised the app)

1. User logged in via dialog
2. Store user with an ID/session(or password, however your app works) and store the token
3. When next the app recognises the session (whether it be a cookie management system you set or a simple user/pass setup), retrieve the token from the database and debug it https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/debug_token
   4a. Is token valid? Yes, don't invoke login dialog
   4b. Is token invald, Invoke dialog

How the debug token call works

`https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN_STORED_IN_DB&access_token=APP_TOKEN`

Response

```
{
  "data": {
    "app_id": "APP_ID", 
    "application": "APP_NAME", 
    "expires_at": 1422295200, 
    "is_valid": true, 
    "scopes": [
      "public_profile", 
      "read_mailbox", 
      "read_page_mailboxes", 
      "ads_management", 
      "ads_read", 
      "manage_pages", 
      "publish_actions"
    ], 
    "user_id": "USER_ID"
  }
}
```

If the token is invalid an error will be returned in the response as well, with `is_valid` set to false.

```
{
  "data": {
    "app_id": "APP_ID", 
    "application": "AnyLeepingTest", 
    "error": {
      "code": 190, 
      "message": "Error validating access token: Session has expired on Jan 9, 2015 7:00pm. The current time is Jan 26, 2015 8:22am.", 
      "subcode": 463
    }, 
    "expires_at": 1420858800, 
    "is_valid": false, 
    "profile_id": "PROFILE_ID", 
    "scopes": [
      "public_profile", 
      "read_mailbox", 
      "read_page_mailboxes", 
      "ads_management", 
      "ads_read", 
      "manage_pages", 
      "publish_actions"
    ], 
    "user_id": "USER_ID"
  }
}
```

So as long as you store the last access token retrieved from the user you will be able to tell whether he user is already logged into your app.

---

If you don't store the token and want to figure out login status, well, that's a bit more complex.

The only token you can generate automatically in cURL (without user interaction) is an application access token.

User interaction isn't just a Facebook standard. It's actually stated in OAuth specification

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

> Before initiating the protocol, the client registers with the
> authorization server.  The means through which the client registers
> with the authorization server are beyond the scope of this
> specification but typically involve end-user interaction with an HTML
> registration form.

There are ways Facebook internally generates user access tokens for the developer explorer tool, and some of their native apps, but this relies on trust between Facebook and the user. Facebook does not offer developers that level of trust because we are third party developers.

Now for more technical information of why this cannot work in a large scale setting

[image: Server Flow]

This is how all server side flows look, SDK or no SDK.
The first, third and fourth legs can all be done in the background. The second leg

> User accepts dialog and is sent to `redirect_uri` with `code` parameter included

Is what to be of concerned with, basically when the user clicks the button in the dialog here, a `POST` request is made to

`https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth/read`

```
fb_dtsg:FB_DTSG
app_id:APP_ID
redirect_uri:https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/callback
display:page
access_token:
sdk:
from_post:1
public_info_nux:1
private:
login:
read:public_profile,baseline
write:
readwrite:
extended:
social_confirm:
confirm:
seen_scopes:public_profile,baseline
auth_type:
auth_token:
auth_nonce:
default_audience:
ref:Default
return_format:code
domain:
sso_device:
sheet_name:initial
__CONFIRM__:1
__user:13608786
__a:1
__dyn:...
__req:4
ttstamp:...
__rev:...
```

So as can be seen above, it should be noted that for this POST request to work in cURL you need `fb_dtsg` of the user which is used for defending against CSRF attacks, so you will not be able to get this.

On subsequent requests for the token (assuming, no additional permissions are asked), you wouldn't need the `fb_dtsg` token though one still has to hit this endpoint you want to cURL with

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL&scope=MY_APPROVED_SCOPE`

In here Facebook checks which user is hitting this endpoint, the only way for this to work will be with valid cookies

- datr
- lu
- c_user
- fr
- xs
- s
- act

ref:[Facebook Ireland Audit Review Report_21 Sept 2012](https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/851576_193932070769264_1415834022_n.pdf)

Now assuming you can get the fb_dtsg and the valid cookie session data, with your cURL request you will still have to emulate a browser by sending a user agent as Facebook picks up on machines crawling the site.

So your cURL request will actually be more along the lines of

`curl 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth/read' -H 'origin: https://www.facebook.com' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_id=819244098116110&redirect_uri=FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL' -H 'cookie: datr=...; lu=...; c_user=...; fr=...; xs=...; csm=2; s=...; wd=1408x472; act=...' --data 'fb_dtsg=...&app_id=819244098116110&redirect_uri=FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL&display=page&access_token=&sdk=&from_post=1&public_info_nux=1&private=&login=&read=public_profile%2Cbaseline&write=&readwrite=&extended=&social_confirm=&confirm=&seen_scopes=public_profile%2Cbaseline&auth_type=&auth_token=&auth_nonce=&default_audience=&ref=Default&return_format=code&domain=&sso_device=&sheet_name=initial&__CONFIRM__=1&__user=13608786&__a=1&__dyn=...&__req=4&ttstamp=...&__rev=...' --compressed`

After which you will get the response as

`for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":null,"jsmods":{"require":[["ServerRedirect","redirectPageTo",[],["https:FACEBOOK_REDIRECT_URL?code=CODE_PARAM#_=_",true]]]},"js":["J93Wm"],"bootloadable":{},"resource_map":{"J93Wm":{"type":"js","crossOrigin":1,"src":"https:\/\/fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net\/rsrc.php\/v2\/yg\/r\/IZE34GLft38.js"}},"ixData":{},"lid":"0"}`

So yeah browser simulation is tricky and depends on many factor and trust levels the majority of your users will not supply to you, because basically for all this to work, you need the user's password.

All of the above goes without saying, this is just theory work showing how one will have to go about with no user initiated flows. As mentioned before in the comments, this both against Facebook TOS and Facebook Developer Policy, so I think the risk of jeopardising your developer account, personal account, applications and customers outweighs the benefits of not having to deal with user interaction.

Maybe try sending a pull request to update the PHP SDK to your liking? https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/pulls :)